# Intellisense ignoring assembly reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense, assembly-references

I have a Project assembly reference from one project in my solution to another.

It appears that VS2010's Intellisense doesn't realise the reference is there; it gives me

- an error `The type or namespace name [assembly-specific part of namespace] does not exist in the namespace [namespace common to both projects/assemblies] (are you missing an assembly reference?)` in my `using` statement
- an error `The name [class in referenced assembly] does not exist in the current context` at the point where I use a class from the referenced assembly.

However, the reference works fine in practice: the referencing project builds successfully, and the code works fine.

(Both projects are targeted at the same framework. If it's relevant, this is a SharePoint project, so both assemblies live in the GAC; I don't know whether this means they could "find" each other even if the reference is in fact missing.)

I've had similar issues referencing this assembly from other assemblies before. Generally the error only stays in the Error List while the file with the reference in is open.

As everything builds fine, this is really just an annoyance, but I would really like to fix it.

Comment: Check if there's a mismatch between target .NET frameworks in the projects, particularly full vs client.

Comment: They're both targeted at 3.5 full. Wouldn't this cause the build, or at least actual operation, to fail if they were wrong?

Comment: I think this also occurs if your project targets **x86**, but the referenced assembly targets **Any CPU** although this is not a problem for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was targeting the Client Profile by default. When I changed it to the non-client profile target framework it compiled properly.

Note that this issue can also manifest itself as the reverse problem where Intellisense works, but it won't compile.

[image]

Comment: brilliant! I had this error show up when updating from VS2013 to VS2015. please note: this must be fixed in the missing reference project, not the project reporting the error.